# In Aggrid Reactnumber filter not working for N/A

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

`In my aggrid react i am passing N/A so i want that in number filter when i put 0 it will show all the N/A values

`{   headerName: 'Med Value',   field: 'med_value',   filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',   valueGetter: ({ data }) => {     if (data.phenotype_type === 'Continuous') {       return Number(data.med_value);     }     return N/A;   }

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.